# Firefox sporadically loses ability to perform DNS lookups

Tags: windows-7, networking, firefox, dns, ipv6

I've scoured the web for several days now, essentially every single time I encounter this. I hope someone here knows a solution to this.

### Facts

- I'm using the latest stable release of Firefox at the time of writing.
- I'm running on Dual Stack (native IPv4 *and* native IPv6).
- Any tab exhibits the symptom as soon as you refresh or open a new URL.
- **No other browser or client is affected.** I can use Opera, Internet Explorer, PuTTY etc without any such symptoms while Firefox continues to show me "Server not found".
- **NB:** The DNS cache service on my box is turned off (meaning `ipconfig /flushdns` is out of the picture).

This remains unsolved as of July 2016. I still experience the DNS "outages" which seem to affect only Firefox.

### Symptoms

I recently switched to Firefox and I am experiencing "Server not found" errors in intervals from less than an hour to several days.

[image]

This happens out of the blue, except that when I disconnect Cisco AnyConnect, this seems to be a sure-shot way of exposing this behavior. The issue, however, also occurs sporadically without any VPN software even running.

### Stuff I researched and tried

I tried <kbd>F5</kbd> obviously, but that *never* worked. The only thing that works *reliably* is to restart Firefox. Personally, that would mean I would have to switch browser again, as this behavior is simply unacceptable.

I found [this several year old thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/74766/Why-does-my-Firefox-lose-its-ability-to-do-DNS-lookups) which suggests turning off IPv6, which is also recommended [over at mozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Error_loading_any_website). In fact this prompted me several days ago to turn both IPv6 and DNS prefetching off by setting the following options in `about:config`:

```
network.dns.disableIPv6=true
network.dns.disablePrefetch=true
```

Yet I have seen the symptoms again in the days since the configuration change (I have since reset those two options).

Now what I found flabbergasting was that when I looked at the outgoing requests from my machine using Wireshark *while* attempting to refresh the tabs that showed those symptoms, I saw **not a single DNS request**: zero, nada. What I saw instead were NBNS requests, i.e. "NetBIOS Name Service". And in fact the requests contained the very names of domains I was trying to access from Firefox.

Please note that *after* restarting Firefox, I can see these NBNS requests also for cases were a standard DNS lookup fails (not the "connection", but the *lookup* fails, I can see DNS responses). That is [`wpad`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) for example fails to resolve via DNS in the intranet and then internet and then ends up as an attempt via NBNS.

### Question

How can I either prevent this from happening in the first place or *when* it happens recover from it without having to restart Firefox? This being: Firefox losing its ability to resolve server names via DNS.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the `network.dnsCacheExpiration` option? Set it to `0` to disable internal Firefox cache.

Comment: Also, when problem occurs next time, instead of restarting Firefox try to `Clear Recent History` with only `Cache` being checked.

Comment: @Nikolay: I have not. Will set it to 0 now. I'd like to avoid clear recent history if I can, but I'll give it a spin at least, so see whether it can help resolve the issue. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Also, take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13063496/1418463) at StackOverflow. It is about Firefox DNS cache.

Comment: I have been experiencing the issue again, so `network.dnsCacheExpiration=0` didn't help.

Comment: Ok. `about:networking` could be helpful also. Try to use it (`DNS` tab) to see if there is anything strange. In my Firefox browser I see number of hosts that I've visited recently and their appropriate IP addresses with DNS cache expiration time.

Comment: @Nikolay: only saw this now. Yes, this looks useful indeed. Will try to make use of that next time it happens. Happened some minutes ago which led me to another hunt for solutions ending up at my own (unsolved) question again.

Comment: I started having this issue about 2 months ago after using firefox on my mac without issues for 3 years... Really annoying... Makes me wonder about security... None of the solutions here have helped... It's sporadic, and last for a couple of minutes, and then starts working again without the restarting. I have to open the websites in Chrome browser to prevent closing all tabs during these blackouts, and they do not affect all sites. Random sites keep working during the dns blackouts...

Answer (score 2):

A couple of months ago I had exactly the same problem with Firefox. Same symptoms, only Firefox stopped to resolve addresses... opera, chrome, ie, etc. all worked like a charm, I restarted Firefox and all working fine but just a few minutes. As far as I know, the only difference with you is that I was using Firefox Portable from portableapps.com. I reinstalled it a lot of times and tried all that you can imagine but I get nothing so I switched to Portable version of Firefox ESR (Extended Support Release) and with this version I had zero issues but it is an old version (31.7).

Well, two weeks ago I decided to try it again with last Firefox Portable version 38.0.5 and the same problem... but this time I found a Firefox profile in %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles so I removed it (Firefox should be stopped) and that's all, for some reason I can't explain, that profile was causing the DNS issues, since then, zero issues with last Firefox Portable version.

It is something you could try to check, maybe you have some corrupt profile that is causing some conflict, you could try to delete the profiles and Firefox will create a new one in the next start, but please, before delete anything, backup backup backup ;).

Sorry, I know this is not an answer but I can't add a comment.

Comment: How is this not an answer? Sure there's a lot of fluff, but deleting profiles sounds like a good solution (for the reasons you gave). If you remove the fluff, this would be a better answer.

Comment: @Cfinley: it *is* an answer (which is why I upvoted it), but how is removing the profile **ever** a good idea? For starters it means that I need to start over, *losing everything* in my profile (using backup/restore might obviously reintroduce the "corruption"). It also means that something that might be a bug in Firefox goes unfixed, because we dodge the question: what is the *ultimate* **cause**? Where do you see the causal connection between profile and experienced failures? If a restart with the *exact same* profile works, how can it primarily be "the profile's fault"?

Answer (score 2):

I found it was only the cert8.db file that required deleting from the profile folder to resolve the issue for me which is a lot less drastic than deleting your entire profile.
I would notice that a specific site with a self signed certificate would take longer and longer to load over a period of days and weeks until eventually I'd get nothing except the "Server not found" message. Now my solution is

Close Firefox
Navigate to %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
Delete cert8.db file
Restart Firefox

Comment: But you write that a restart is still required. But that's exactly what I want to avoid. Right now I can get it to work *again* by restarting FF and then it works for a few hours or days. But the restart is what is unnecessary. Thanks anyway for sharing your findings.

Comment: I think the restart refers to starting firefox again after deleting the file...

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. (I'm using a Dicrect Access VPN).
Though I have no solution for the issue, I have a step forward in investigation:
As suggested in a comment above I took a look on about:networking
When attempting to access a intranet host I've got 2 different entries in DNS tab:
intranet_host   ipv4    172.x.x.x   110
intranet_host   ipv4    fdcb:xxxx:xxxx::acxx:xxxx   109

Randomly, accessing the intranet_host will fail.
Accessing instead intranet_host.my_domain.com always work. Again 2 entries exists in DNS tab:
intranet_host.my_domain.com ipv6    fdcb:xxxx:xxxx::acxx:xxxx   97
intranet_host.my_domain.com ipv4    fdcb:xxxx:xxxx::acxx:xxxx   97

To be noted in both cases these are inappropriate address family used.
I opened a bug on mozilla for this: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1174249

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have finally found a way to solve the the issue without having to restart firefox:
Settings network.proxy.socks_remote_dns;true made firefox to send again DNS requests. Subsequent resettings to default did not bring back (for the moment) to DNS silent status.

Comment: Great. You should edit your answer and add the information about the solution from your comment ... ;)

Comment: Changing network.proxy.socks_remote_dns to 'true' finally did the trick for me.